Adding local interpreter in PyCharm disabled
I updated PyCharm CE 2019 to PyCharm CE 2024. Previously, I was able to create and add a local interpreter which generates a venv directory for the project but after updating, this feature seems disabled for me and I cannot find a reason why this is happening or solution to fix this.
I am working on a Sonoma MacOS.
Attached below is an image of the window when adding a local interpreter. You can see that the "Ok" button is disabled.


Does the venv folder already exists?

No. It didn't need to back then in the 2019 version but I also tried creating an empty venv folder just to see if t would allow it but still nothing. What I'm doing for now is using python3 -m venv venv and link that directory to my project as my interpreter but I would still want to know why my current problem is happening.
